# Persistent volume updates not reflected in pod deployed with helm without a re-deployment

Tags: kubernetes, cron, kubernetes-helm, persistent-volumes

I have this persistent volume created as a part of deployment with helm. The setup contains a cronjob, a persistent volume and a persistent volume claim.

Everything is done in same namespace

Cronjob updates files in persistent volume:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: somename
  namespace: my-ns
spec:
  concurrencyPolicy: Allow
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 1
  jobTemplate:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          affinity: {}
          containers:
            - command:
                - /bin/sh
                - '-c'
                - <code to update file in persistent volume>
              volumeMounts:
                - name: mountedvol
                  mountPath: /var/local/mounted_vol
          volumes:
            - name: mountedvol
              persistentVolumeClaim:
                claimName:  pvc01
  schedule: '*/22 * * * *'
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 3
  suspend: false
```

Persistent volume

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mypv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 200Mi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
      - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: i_tried_w_and_w/o_storage_name
  hostPath:
    path: /mnt/a_path
```

my pvc

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: pvc01
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: i_tried_w_and_w/o_storage_name
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 200Mi
```

Pod which access persistent volume

```
volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /var/local/my_data
      name: myvol
volumes:
 - name: myvol
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: my_pvc
```

This is deployed with helm.

Whenever cronjob update persistent volume, like a editing an existing file or adding a new file, it is not reflected in the other pod. But when the other pod is redeployed, updates are reflected. What is more strange is that sometimes after first deployment also cron's update on pv is not picked up by the other pod.

I created a new pod with matching volume and volume mounts. I did so in rancher UI by uploading yaml template. To my surprise, I can see all the updates made by cron job in the pv from these pods. I tried with multiple pods. I can see updates on pv. I updated pv from a pod and it is visible in the other pods and the pod that runs cronjob.

Am I missing something in helm setup which makes helm to force something like a pvc refresh?  Is that the way to go? My knowledge on kubernetes is very limited. I am working on kubernetes since last 3-4 days only. I am not sure what am I doing wrong or there is some bug with helm as all deployments and components are visible in kubernetes backend with kubectl

Comment: That `hostPath` volume will refer to a directory on whichever node the Pod happens to be running on; do you have any way to verify if the CronJob is littering files on to other Nodes around the cluster?  You shouldn't normally need to manually create the PersistentVolume, but conversely, a ReadWriteMany volume can be a little hard to get.

Comment: Oh.. Yes it is running in different nodes. Much thanks for pointer. Is it possible to select node with affinity/selector?

Answer (score 0):

As per David Maze's comment, I checked and saw that cronjob's pod and other pod was running on separate nodes. I added nodeselector to both cronjob and other pod

Deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: "apps/v1"
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  ...
spec:
  ...
  selector:
    ...
  template:
    ...
    spec:
      ...
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/hostname: "my_node_name"
```

Cronjob.yaml

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  ...
spec:
  ...
  jobTemplate:
    metadata:
      ...
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          nodeSelector:
            kubernetes.io/hostname: "my_node_name"
          affinity: {}
          containers:
          ...
```

This solved the issue